# Filtering for multiple ForeignKey matches using Q objects

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-1.3, django-q

I've initialized these models with the following data in an app named `main` under Django 1.3:

```
from django.db.models import Model, FloatField, CharField, ForeignKey, Q

class Customer(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=64)

class Order(Model):
    customer = ForeignKey(Customer)
    order_total = FloatField()
```

```
c = Customer(name="John Smith")
c.save()

Order(customer=c, order_id=9).save()
Order(customer=c, order_id=13).save()
```

How can I construct a query using `Q()` objects to find the Customer that owns order 9 and order 13?

Without using `Q()` objects, I can use the `.filter()` method twice to get the result I want. As you can see, it uses two `JOIN`s to look up the two foreign keys:

```
queryset = Customer.objects.filter(order__order_id=9).filter(order__order_id=13)

return HttpResponse("%s\n\n%s" % (queryset, queryset.query), content_type="text/plain")
```

```sql
[<Customer: Customer object>]

SELECT "main_customer"."id", "main_customer"."name"
FROM "main_customer"
INNER JOIN "main_order" ON ("main_customer"."id" = "main_order"."customer_id")
INNER JOIN "main_order" T3 ON ("main_customer"."id" = T3."customer_id")
WHERE ("main_order"."order_id" = 9  AND T3."order_id" = 13 )
```

I tried to do the same thing using `Q()` objects as follows. Instead of understanding that I was referring to two different Orders, one with id 9 and one with id 13, it thinks that I'm looking for a single order with both ids 9 and 13. This is obviously impossible, so it returns no results:

```
q = Q(order__order_id=9) & Q(order__order_id=13)
queryset = Customer.objects.filter(q)

return HttpResponse("%s\n\n%s" % (queryset, queryset.query), content_type="text/plain")
```

```sql
[]

SELECT "main_customer"."id", "main_customer"."name"
FROM "main_customer"
INNER JOIN "main_order" ON ("main_customer"."id" = "main_order"."customer_id")
WHERE ("main_order"."order_id" = 9  AND "main_order"."order_id" = 13 )
```

I expected Django's engine to interpret both queries equivalently, but apparently `Q()` objects are handled differently. How can I filter an object by multiple foreign key references using `Q()` objects, instead of calling `.filter()` multiple times?

Comment: I wasn't sure how best to describe what I'm trying to do. New title suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a workaround to this situation:

Using `filter( ~(~Q(A) | ~Q(B)) )` instead of `filter(Q(A) & Q(B))` seems to yield the expected result.

This is based on the fact that `A and B` is equivalent to `not ( not(A) or not(B) )` and enables filtering on multiple `ForeignKey` using only `Q` objects (ultimately passed to a single `filter`). It is rather ugly, but still uses only one database query in the end.

As pointed out above, the original problem comes from the different behaviors of `.filter(A).filter(B)` and `filter(A & B)` (see the example in [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)), and `filter(Q(A) & Q(B))` replicates only one of those uses.

The generated SQL queries in my case where too complicated to make sure that this workaround was perfectly working, but I thought I'd share the idea since my tests proved it to work. Please let me know if you definitely prove it/break it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not really using Django much these days so I can't test it myself, but hopefully who is will come across this post some time, find it useful, and may be able to leave a comment letting us know if it worked for them.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [an explanation for this in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships). The behaviour I observed is the expected behaviour; query terms for multi-valued relationships are treated differently if they're applied within the same call to `.filter()`/`.exclude()` than if they're applied within different calls.

If I apply the two query terms within the same `.filter()` call...

```py
queryset = Customer.objects.filter(Q(order__order_id=9) & Q(order__order_id=13))
# or equivalently: .objects.filter(Q(order__order_id=9), Q(order__order_id=13))
```

...then it only returns `Customer`s that own any orders which satisfy both constraints, `order_id=9 AND order_id=13`. The terms must refer to the same `Order` at any given time.

On the other hand, if I apply the query terms using two different `.filter()` calls...

```
queryset = Customer.objects.filter(order__order_id=9).filter(order__order_id=13)
```

...they do not need to refer to the same `Order`. This could be seen as a two-step operation: the set of all `Customer`s is filtered down to those owning any `Order`s satisfying `order_id=9`. This result set then is furthered filtered to those `Customer`s also owning any `Order` satisfying `order_id=13`. It could be the same `Order` in both cases. It doesn't matter; the steps are isolated from each other.

There *may* be some way to get this behaviour from `Q()` objects with a single `.filter()` call, but it doesn't look like that's the way Django's ORM is meant to be used.

Comment: If somebody *can* find some way of making this work with a single `.filter()`/`.exclude()` call, I would be very interested, and if it's even remotely usable you're entitled to the accept answer mark for actually answering the question.